# Unknown word is coming from the pages in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am getting child pages of a specific page. below is my code.

```
<div class="col-sm-3 services">
    <h3>SERVICES</h3>
    <?php $get_subcategories = wp_list_pages(array('child_of'=>39)); ?>
    <ul>
        <?php foreach($get_subcategories as $subcategory){?>
               <li><a href="services-detail.html"><?php echo $subcategory->name;?></a></li>
       <?php }?>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Here is the output of above code.

[image]

**Problem:** I am getting an additional word PAGES also. which is encircled in the above image.

*From where this words is coming, and how to hide this ?*

Comment: Is it in the same <ul> list? Doesn't appear to use the same style as the rest so wondering if it's not coming from this code. Also, am I the only one bothered that `Crowns & bridges` isn't uppercase? :P

Comment: Can you show us a few lines above/below your PHP excerpt? Have you tried right-clicking on it and using "Inspect element" to see what portion of the HTML it's in?

Comment: @ceejayoz it is updated

Comment: `wp_list_pages` returns an HTML string, trying to loop over this with foreach makes no sense to begin with. The line `<?php $get_subcategories = wp_list_pages(...); ?>` creates the output you see here already, because the default behavior of this function is to echo out the result. After that you create an _additional_ UL, which will contain nothing (except for an error message saying you can not loop over a string, if those aren’t suppressed.) You really need to learn to go read up on how the functions you are using actually work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here i solved the issues of showing default title and bullet points on each list item, by following the guidelines of @Gavin & @misorude i changed the above code and now it is working fine.

```
<div class="col-sm-3 services">
    <h3>SERVICES</h3>
    <ul>
        <?php $get_subpages = wp_list_pages(array('child_of'=>39,'title_li'=>'')); ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a default from the `wp_list_pages()` function.

Source: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_pages/

You need to enter your `title_li`

```
<?php $get_subcategories = wp_list_pages(array('child_of'=>39, 'title_li' => '')); ?>
```

Comment: solved issue, another issue is up..which is that after adding the `title_li` bullet is showing in each list item. how to hide this?

Comment: As in it's adding an empty list item or just bullet points to your current list? If it's the latter, then it's a CSS issue.